# Nested cmake library

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cmake

We have a `C/C++` project organized like this:

```
lib1/
    CMakeLists.txt
    sublib1/
        CMakeLists.txt
        foo.c
    log.c
    log.h
```

Directory `sublib1/` is linked with the `add_library` and `target_link_libraries` CMake commands in its `CMakeLists.txt` file.

**Change:**
We cannot call from `foo.c/some-func` a function in `log.c/some-func-2`. Linker is complaining that those functions are undefined.

Comment: Is it the *compiler* or the *linker* complaining? If it's the compiler, have you #included log.h in your foo.c file?

Comment: It's linker, compiler would be easy to fix.

Comment: Are you building the sub-library as a static or shared library? If the sub-library will only be used to link into the top library (if the top library is shared) then you should make the sub-library a static library (`libxxx.a` instead of `libxxx.so`), then there won't be any linking of the sub-library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order that libraries and object files appear in your link command matters and can result in perplexing problems with undefined symbols.  You don't give much info your post, but try telling the linker to treat all your libraries as a group.  As in:

```
--start-group <all your libs> --end-group
```

From the linker documentation:

> Normally, an archive is searched only once in the order that it is specified on the command line. If a symbol in that archive is needed to resolve an undefined symbol referred to by an object in an archive that appears later on the command line, the linker would not be able to resolve that reference. By grouping the archives, they all be searched repeatedly until all possible references are resolved. Using this option has a significant performance cost. It is best to use it only when there are unavoidable circular references between two or more archives.